# Order of Textbox methods in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a textbox control that I need to do some customized data validation on.  I've hit the Googles but I can't find anything that tells me which order the methods go in.  Does OnPreRender come before OnTextChanged?  Does anyone know of a webpage that exists that shows the order in which they're fired?

Ideally I'd like to find something like [this list of Access events](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/order-of-events-for-database-objects-HA010238988.aspx).

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/aspnet-basics-the-page-life-cycle/

Comment: And this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I get confused, I create the methods/events, throw some breakpoints on them, hit debug, postback the page, and see what happens. Nothing beats seeing it in work with your own eyes.

Answer (score 4):

This might help - This graphic explains the complete life cycle.

[image: ASP.Net Page and Control Life Cycle]

Comment: This is freakin' EPIC.

Comment: Did you come up with this graphic, or did you borrow it from somewhere? If it's from somewhere else, you need to give proper credit.